# how to make nginx rewirte url from one php to another php

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have a old web application which use get.php to interact with client app. now we upgraded our web application to use laravel framework, which use restful api as url interface,

and our server use nginx, so I want to redirect old url to new url like this:

```
/get.php?update => /update or (index.php/update)
```

I have tried with these config.

```
    location = /get.php?update {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/update;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

but it seems when I access `get.php`, I still get the `404 error`.

So how can I redirect this using nginx's rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx `location` block doesn't match query string, so your try will fail.

Try this:

```
location = /get.php {
    if ($args = update) {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?$query_string last;
    }
}
```

<sub>But `IF` is kinda [evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).</sub>

Comment: thank you, I've successfully resovled this problem by add a missingMethod function to my laravel controller and added this into nginx's config file

        location = /get.php {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

so I let my laravel controller to decided how to process the get.php and options